# Find symlink when 'find' hasn't worked

Tags: bash, unix, find, symbolic-link

So I have a few utility scripts in my ~/scripts folder. They are all bash scripts, nothing amazing about that. One is named `sfind.sh`, the other is `svn-add-all.sh`. At some point, I created symlinks to them, and made them executable. So I can run `sfind.sh` at my prompt as `$ sfind` and `svn-add-all.sh` as `$ addall`.

The problem is, I cannot remember where I put my symlinks. They have to be on my $PATH, but doing an `ls` on the folders in my $PATH hasn't shown anything.

`echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/drush:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

So then I tried doing a system-wide find. Here's what I tried:

```
sudo find / -lname /Users/kyle/scripts/\* -exec ls --color=always {} \;
sudo find / -mount -lname /Users/kyle/scripts/\* -exec ls --color=always {} \;
sudo find / -name "sfind"
sudo find / -lname "sfind"
sudo find / -name "sfind*" -type fl
sudo find / -name "addall"
```

And still I got nothing.

Using `locate` and `which` hasn't worked either. Obviously these links must be available from somewhere.

Is there any way I can find the location of these symlinks?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps did you create shell functions, not symlinks. What says `type sfind` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
type -a sfind
```

since type (in contrast to which) will also find functions and aliases you might have defined in your .bashrc or elsewhere.

Comment: I totally didn't think to look in my .bashrc. I work across 3 machines, and the one with the problem gets the least love. Maybe I outsmarted myself. I'll check back.

Comment: It was in my .bash_aliases file. Thanks. I have them symlinked on my other machines. It was driving me crazy.